# Accessing @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, thymeleaf

I don't seem to get access to my Scoped Proxy Data class Singleton from Thymeleaf in HTML

my data class

```
@Document(collection = "networker")
open class Networker(
    @Id
    var id: String? = null,
    @TextIndexed
    @Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
    var name: String? = null,
....
```

Then my `@Configuration` Bean

```
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    fun networker(): Networker {
        return Networker()
    }
```

Then I get the correct record and add the Model attibute

```
@GetMapping(value = ["index"])
    @ModelAttribute(value = "networker")
    fun profileView(model: Model): String {

        val authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
        val username: String = authentication.name
        networker = networkerRepository.findBySecurityUserName(username)

        model.addAttribute("networker", networker)
        model.addAttribute("networkerSettings", networkerSettings)

        return "profile/index"
    }
```

**I have tried**

1. `<tbody th:object="${networker}">`
2. If I use `th.text="${@networker.name}"` I do not get any content but the compile does not complain
3. I tried things like `th:object="${#servletContext.getAttribute(networker)}"` but none of them showed my data that I can edit

Please refer me to some working sample perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was so simple, I dint need the

```
@Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

At all I just needed to annotate my `@Controller` with `@SessionAttributes("networker")` and the call from the HTML to `th:object="${networker}"` works perfectly